# Variety of homogenous polynomials which factor as the product of linear forms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be the complex vector space of all homogenous polynomials in three variables of degree $d$ and $\mathbf{P}V$ the corresponding projective space. Let $X$ be the subset of all those homogenous polynomials which can be written as the proudct of linear forms. If $Y$ is the variety of all linear forms, then the obvious map $Y^d \to X$ is surjective and finite to one by unique factorization, so $\dim X = 2d$. Can we calculate the degree of $X$ for small $d$, e.g if $d=2,3$, and more generally if more than three variables are allowed?

Comment: I am slightly more generally also interested in tricks to compute the degree of varieties like these. For instance using incidence correspondences one can calculate the dimension of the subvariety of projective space that corresponds to singular hypersurfaces of a given degree, but I don't know any techniaues to calculate the degree of such a variety that is not by explicit computation (which is usually unfeasible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible way of computing the degree. First note that the map $Y^d\to X$ is invariant under the action of $S_d$, the symmetric group. Also, it is easy to see that the generic degree of this map is precisely the order of $S_d$, namely $d!$. So, to calculate the degree of $X$, suffices to identify the pull back of the hyperplane section in $Y^d$. If we restrict the map to a $Y\times p$ where $p\in Y^{d-1}$ is a general point, one easily sees that the hyperplane pulls back to the hyperplane in $Y$. By, symmetry, we see that the hyperplane pulls back to the tensor product of the hyperplanes in each $Y$. So, its degree is $(2d)!/2^d$ and thus the degree of $X$ is $(2d)!/2^d\cdot d!$.